# Large Java JARs won't run over `http`

Tags: java, http, jar

Platform: Win7 32bit, Netbeans 7.1.2, JDK 7, JRE 1.7.0_05.

Web Servers: Ubuntu/Apache and Windows Server 2008/IIS 7.

I have a large Java web applet that works fine when run off the local file system but fails when run over `http` (both servers tested).  I have used APPLET, OBJECT and deployJava.js.  I started out with just an APPLET but am now using Jave Web Start.

Experimentaion has revealed that the problem only occurs with JARs of around 34k or larger.  The current version uses a JWS Applet invoked via the APPLET tag.

All JARS are signed.

JAVA Caching is enabled (to circumvent erroneous "code not signed" errors) but I clear the cache netween each test.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test page for launching the applet via JNLP</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h3>Test page for launching the applet via JNLP</h3>
        <applet width="300" height="300">
            <param name="jnlp_href" value="launch.jnlp"/>
        </applet>
    </body>
</html>
```

JNLP:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<jnlp href="launch.jnlp" spec="1.0+">
    <information>
        <title>cleverAUDIO</title>
        <vendor>ChrisSpray</vendor>
        <homepage href=""/>
        <description>cleverAUDIO</description>
        <description kind="short">cleverAUDIO</description>
    </information>
    <update check="always"/>
    <security>
        <all-permissions/>
</security>
    <resources>
        <j2se java-vm-args="-Djava.security.policy=applet.policy" version="1.7+"/>
        <jar href="cleverAUDIO.jar" main="true"/>
    <jar download="lazy" href="lib/cleverDEBUG.jar"/>
    <jar download="lazy" href="lib/cleverWINDOWS.jar"/>
    <jar download="lazy" href="lib/cleverWinMMDevice.jar"/>
    <jar download="lazy" href="lib/platform.jar"/>
    <jar download="lazy" href="lib/jna.jar"/>
</resources>
    <applet-desc height="300" main-class="uk.co.cleverit.cleverAUDIO.applet" name="cleverAUDIO" width="300">
    </applet-desc>
</jnlp>
```

The full Java log when invoked via the local FILE System is [here](http://cleverit.co.uk/problems/File_Log.txt) and when invoked via `HTTP` [here](http://cleverit.co.uk/problems/HTTP_Log.txt).

Parital FILE log:

```
network: ResponseCode for file:/N:/cleverAUDIO/dist/cleverAUDIO.jar : 200
network: Encoding for file:/N:/cleverAUDIO/dist/cleverAUDIO.jar : null
network: Sever response: (length: 62791, lastModified: Fri Aug 03 14:51:01 BST 2012, downloadVersion: null, mimeType: application/x-java-archive)
network: CleanupThread used 6 us
preloader: Added pending event 2: DownloadEvent[type=load,loaded=0, total=62791, percent=0]
network: Downloading resource: file:/N:/cleverAUDIO/dist/cleverAUDIO.jar
Content-Length: 62,791
Content-Encoding: null
JVM[id=1]-Heartbeat sent heartbeat: [Conversation: id=0, initiatingSide=true] { healthy: true, ageSeconds: 7, availableHeapKB: 248528, appletThreads: 6 }
preloader: Using preloader class: null  com.sun.deploy.uitoolkit.impl.awt.AWTAppletAdapter@1737e47
preloader: Using default preloader
preloader: Requested to use preloader class: null
preloader: Delivering: ConfigEvent[type=SetVisible, value=true]
preloader: Delivering: DownloadEvent[type=load,loaded=0, total=62791, percent=1]
preloader: Skipped all (0) download events prior to DownloadEvent[type=load,loaded=0, total=62791, percent=1]
preloader: Preloader jars loaded. Error state=null
security: Staring warmup validation
preloader: Start progressCheck thread
preloader: GrayBox: parent = sun.plugin2.main.client.PluginEmbeddedFrame[frame0,0,0,300x300,layout=java.awt.BorderLayout,title=,resizable,normal]
preloader: Delivering: DownloadEvent[type=load,loaded=1005, total=62791, percent=1]
<snip>
preloader: Delivering: DownloadEvent[type=load,loaded=62791, total=62791, percent=80]
network: Wrote URL file:/N:/cleverAUDIO/dist/cleverAUDIO.jar to File C:\Users\ChrisSpray\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\cache\6.0\39\9a4cda7-7f8c3d0f-temp
```

Partial `HTTP` log:

```
network: ResponseCode for http://lamp.cleverit.co.uk/includes/cleverAUDIO/cleverAUDIO.jar : 200
network: Encoding for http://lamp.cleverit.co.uk/includes/cleverAUDIO/cleverAUDIO.jar : null
network: Sever response: (length: 62791, lastModified: Fri Aug 03 15:09:41 BST 2012, downloadVersion: null, mimeType: application/java-archive)
network: CleanupThread used 6 us
preloader: Added pending event 2: DownloadEvent[type=load,loaded=0, total=62791, percent=0]
network: Downloading resource: http://lamp.cleverit.co.uk/includes/cleverAUDIO/cleverAUDIO.jar
Content-Length: 62,791
Content-Encoding: null
preloader: Added pending event 3: DownloadEvent[type=load,loaded=1005, total=62791, percent=1]
<snip>
preloader: Added pending event 32: DownloadEvent[type=load,loaded=34440, total=62791, percent=43]
cache: MemoryCache: removed entry http://lamp.cleverit.co.uk/includes/cleverAUDIO/launch.jnlp
preloader: Using preloader class: null com.sun.deploy.uitoolkit.impl.awt.AWTAppletAdapter@60acdc
preloader: Using default preloader
preloader: Requested to use preloader class: null
JVM[id=1]-Heartbeat sent heartbeat: [Conversation: id=0, initiatingSide=true] { healthy: true, ageSeconds: 6, availableHeapKB: 250928, appletThreads: 6 }
preloader: Delivering: ConfigEvent[type=SetVisible, value=true]
preloader: Delivering: DownloadEvent[type=load,loaded=34440, total=62791, percent=1]
preloader: Skipped all (30) download events prior to DownloadEvent[type=load,loaded=34440, total=62791, percent=1]
preloader: Preloader jars loaded. Error state=null
security: Staring warmup validation
preloader: Start progressCheck thread
preloader: GrayBox: parent = sun.plugin2.main.client.PluginEmbeddedFrame[frame0,0,0,300x300,layout=java.awt.BorderLayout,title=,resizable,normal]
JVM[id=1]-Heartbeat round-trip heartbeat took 1003640 microsecs.
JVM[id=1]-Heartbeat sent heartbeat: [Conversation: id=0, initiatingSide=true] { healthy: true, ageSeconds: 8, availableHeapKB: 249559, appletThreads: 8 }
JVM[id=1]-Heartbeat round-trip heartbeat took 1006503 microsecs.
JVM[id=1]-Heartbeat sent heartbeat: [Conversation: id=0, initiatingSide=true] { healthy: true, ageSeconds: 10, availableHeapKB: 250558, appletThreads: 8 }
JVM[id=1]-Heartbeat round-trip heartbeat took 1005683 microsecs.
preloader: Stop progressCheck thread
```

As you can see, processing stopped after 34440 bytes but the JAR is 62791 bytes long!

No errors or exceptions are produced anywhere (that I can see).

I've spent a week on this problem and, apart from increasing my knowledge, am not getting anywhere with it despite trying numerous variations.
Anybody got any bright ideas?

Many thanks in anticipation

Chris

Comment: Try unpacking the JAR on the server, since the .class files hopefully are smaller than 34K.

Comment: Thanks Gilbert. I unpacked them but then found that JNLP only looks inside JARs - it doesn't download individual classes from the webserver.  So then I stopped using JNLP and sure enough, the individual classes are downloaded and the applet starts. BUT, my code has to be signed because it requires raised privileges and, as far as I know, one can only sign JARs.

Comment: I'll split my large JARs into multiple projects/JARs and see how that goes.  As I use JNA I'll have to manually repackage its JARs as well.

Comment: After much investigation I finally found a reference to AVG causing problems.  Sue enough, disablinbg both SURF-SHIELD and ONLINE SHIELD cured the problem.

Well that was two weeks wasted :(